# Cumulative output format resulting in NAs when using dismo::predict function in R

Tags: r, output, predict, maxent, dismo

I have run a maxent model using the dismo package in R. I am able to use the predict function to view the output format as "raw" or "cloglog" but when I try the "cumulative" format I get "NA" values and a blank output. In summary, this code works fine and produces coloured maps:

```
mxPred <- predict(object = mx, x = bioRastersClipBiolnoCorr, args=c("outputformat=raw"),
                  filename=paste0(filePath, '/maxent_predictionRAW.tif'), overwrite = TRUE)
plot(mxPred, col=rgb.tables(1000))

mxPredClog <- predict(object = mx, x = bioRastersClipBiolnoCorr, args=c("outputformat=cloglog"),
                      filename=paste0(filePath, '/maxent_predictionCLOG.tif'), overwrite = TRUE)
plot(mxPredClog, col=rgb.tables(1000))
```

This code produces no map, just NA values and a blank plot:

```
mxPredCumu <- predict(object = mx, x = bioRastersClipBiolnoCorr, args=c("outputformat=cumulative"),
                  filename=paste0(filePath, '/maxent_predictionCUMU.tif'), overwrite = TRUE)
plot(mxPredCumu, col=rgb.tables(1000))
```

Please help, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Only `raw`, `clolog`, or `logistic` can be set in output format. Choose `raw`  then convert the output to cumulative format.
See [details](https://www.researchgate.net/post/Transforming_Raw_Maxent_output_into_logistic_or_probability_with_ENMeval_in_R/5e8613f0eba15e7b670e6d31/citation/download).